# No library found for namespace http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui in netbean how to set namepace?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xml-namespaces

I tried with primeFace. There is an error on "xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" this line.

How to solve this problem. Please show the all the steps.

Comment: Learn that you need to provide the error, provide the PrimeFaces version, provide the example code

Answer (score 2):

The docs from PrimeFaces are defining this namespace definition as minimum set for a JSF View:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

    <h:head>  

    </h:head>  

    <h:body>  

        <p:spinner />  

    </h:body>  
</html>
```

Ref: http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted

Your fault is in the URL! It is www.primefaces.org and not www.primefaces.com.tr

Comment: Bt there are errors in

<p:dataTable var="user" value="#
{userManagedBean.searchUsersResults}"

                             selection="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser}" 
selectionMode="single"

                             dynamic="true"/>

Comment: And? Has nothing to do with your question. Did it work or not?

Comment: @ReneM.: Keep in mind that the namestaace MIGHT be correct if an older PF version is used. So Asking for a version, the error and more is initially better (but I think you are right ;-) and a little googling by the OP should have provided an answer if he searched in combination with the error

Comment: If he would be smart he would look inside his primefaces jars to find the taglib definitions, there is the correct namespace included ;) Best practice when living in an open source world. Read the source code of that world ;)

Comment: if he is smart, a simple search in stackoverflow would have resulted in a duplicate ;-) Waaaaay easier than searching in the code if you do not know what to look for

Comment: Lets stop here ;) And start searching SO for real questions